# Code runs when admin user logged on the Server with Rdp

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, execution, rdp

I wrote some code in c# and it is called from Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 on my company server. I have a "Download" button on a CRM form. When I press this button, it fires the code under the mvc project controller function which is in CRM server machine. It opens an Excel template in this server and gets info from CRM database. When it gives this form to the calling client user, it translates it to pdf and gives the pdf form to the client user. The code does not write anything to the excel file which is used as an template. 
My problem is when I enter to the server as CRM admin using Rdp, the code executes perfectly and give the pdf to the client user. However, when I close the rdp, the code does not work. I looked to the dconfig from the server the everything is ok. 
How can I solve this problem?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has an important disclaimer regarding this sort of usage:

"Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment."
https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office

You could try the following: 
 - Create a local admin on that server with a non-expiring password.
 - Set up the application’s IIS app pool to run as that specific user
 - Modify the server’s DCOM identity to the new user
Per this Microsoft blog: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2014/09/25/com-client-failing-with-error-8000401a/

Comment: Hi, i did the things below but nothing changed. The porblem still exists

Comment: You could try the following: 
- Create a local admin on that server with a non-expiring password.
- Set up the application’s IIS app pool to run as that specific user
- Modify the server’s DCOM identity to the new user

Comment: I tries this also that you mentioned. However it fails the problem continues. Is there a way to make the interactive user always on on rdp to the server?

Comment: Can we do a trick to deceive the server that someone is connected with rdp.